# A strange straight horizontal line is appearing in the plot

Tags: plotting

```
b1 = {1.8743, 1.8784, 1.88248, 1.89049, 1.89828, 1.90587, 1.91327, 
  1.96335, 2.03035, 2.12536, 2.23701, 2.30098, 2.34255, 2.37175, 
  2.3934, 2.42334, 2.44307, 2.48725, 2.51208, 2.5173, 2.52799, 
  2.53164, 2.53348, 2.53533, 2.53625, 2.53745, 2.53793, 2.53894, 
  2.53909, 2.53543}
b2 = {4.69367, 4.69699, 4.70034, 4.70701, 4.71363, 4.72021, 4.72675, 
   4.77457, 4.84965, 4.98446, 5.20483, 5.37646, 5.51306, 5.62373, 
   5.71474, 5.85448, 5.9557, 6.20643, 6.35701, 6.38884, 6.45382, 
   6.47579, 6.48682, 6.49788, 6.50342, 6.51055, 6.5134, 6.51939, 
   6.52013, 6.52016};
b3 = {7.85466, 7.85573, 7.8568, 7.85896, 7.86111, 7.86327, 7.86542, 
   7.88165, 7.90884, 7.96374, 8.07494, 8.1869, 8.29843, 8.40858, 
   8.5166, 8.72433, 8.91931, 9.69739, 10.484, 10.6298, 10.8023, 
   10.8332, 10.8456, 10.8564, 10.8613, 10.8672, 10.8694, 10.8739, 
   10.8743, 10.8743};
b4 = {10.9954, 10.9955, 10.9955, 10.9955, 10.9956, 10.9957, 10.9957, 
   10.9961, 10.9969, 10.9984, 11.0014, 11.0047, 11.0081, 11.0116, 
   11.0154, 11.0235, 11.0324, 11.0955, 11.3746, 11.5723, 12.2776, 
   12.5831, 12.7365, 12.8841, 12.9543, 13.0401, 13.0729, 13.1386, 
   13.1457, 13.1457};
ks1 = {0.01, 1., 2., 4., 6., 8., 10., 25., 50., 100., 200., 300., 
  400., 500., 600., 800., 1000., 2000., 4000., 5000., 10000., 15000., 
  20000., 30000., 40000., 70000., 100000., 1.*10^6, 1.*10^8, 1.*10^12}

s1 = Normal[
   ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose[{ks1, b1}], Joined -> True, Mesh -> 12,
     MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}, MeshStyle -> Black, 
    PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}, AxesStyle -> Black]] /. 
  Point[pt_] :> Inset[Style["\[SixPointedStar]", 60], pt]
s2 = Normal[
   ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose[{ks1, b2}], Joined -> True, Mesh -> 12,
     MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}, MeshStyle -> Black, 
    PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}, AxesStyle -> Black]] /. 
  Point[pt_] :> Inset[Style["\[EmptySquare]", 60], pt]
s3 = Normal[
   ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose[{ks1, b3}], Joined -> True, Mesh -> 12,
     MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}, MeshStyle -> Black, 
    PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}, AxesStyle -> Black]] /. 
  Point[pt_] :> Inset[Style["\[EmptyUpTriangle]", 60], pt]
s4 = Normal[
   ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose[{ks1, b4}], Joined -> True, Mesh -> 12,
     MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}, MeshStyle -> Black, 
    PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}, AxesStyle -> Black]] /. 
  Point[pt_] :> Inset[Style["\[EmptyCircle]", 60], pt]
fig = Show[s1, s2, s3, s4, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
  PlotRange -> Automatic, 
  FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(K\), \(1\)]\)", "\[Beta]"}, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", 40, GrayLevel[0]}]
fig = Style[fig, GraphicsBoxOptions -> {ImageSize -> 1000}]
```

I have a set of data and I have plotted that data seperately. I clubed  all the plots together using Show function, but I notice an strange horizantal line from nowhere is appearing in my final plot(near y=2), I dont know from where it is coming. In all the indivisula plots this straight horizantal line is not appearing , but in my final plot it is apperaing. How to overcome this and what is the reason for this?

Comment: It's the horizontal axis from the first plot - `Show[…, Axes->False]` fixes the issue

Answer (score 1):

The horizontal line is the x-axis from `s1`.  The easiest way to get rid of it is to set `Axes -> False` in your call to `Show`.

Also, I'd set `ImageSize -> 1000` inside `Show` as well unless you have a specific reason to use `Style`.